# How to set up on Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Virtualbox for Edx Stanford Compiler Course

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, tar

https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+3T2020/6b750292e90d4950b895f621a5671b49/

I am trying to untar the downloaded package and it keeps failing.

```
nyck33@nyck33-VirtualBox:/usr/class$ wget https://courses.edx.org/asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz
--2022-12-29 19:45:59--  https://courses.edx.org/asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz
Resolving courses.edx.org (courses.edx.org)... 104.16.177.84, 104.16.178.84, 104.16.179.84, ...
Connecting to courses.edx.org (courses.edx.org)|104.16.177.84|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5773538 (5.5M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz.1’

asset-v1:StanfordOnlin 100%[=========================>]   5.51M  2.59MB/s    in 2.1s    

2022-12-29 19:46:03 (2.59 MB/s) - ‘asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz.1’ saved [5773538/5773538]

nyck33@nyck33-VirtualBox:/usr/class$ ls
asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz
asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz.1
nyck33@nyck33-VirtualBox:/usr/class$ tar -xf asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz.1
tar: Cannot connect to asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz.1: resolve failed
nyck33@nyck33-VirtualBox:/usr/class$ tar -xf student-dist.tar.gz.1
tar: student-dist.tar.gz.1: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
nyck33@nyck33-VirtualBox:/usr/class$
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in `man tar`:

> ```
>       An archive name that has a colon in it specifies a file  or  de‐
>       vice on a remote machine.  The part before the colon is taken as
>       the machine name or IP address, and the part  after  it  as  the
>       file or device pathname, e.g.:
>
>        --file=remotehost:/dev/sr0
> ```

GNU tar provides a `--force-local` option to override this default behavior

```
   --force-local
          Archive file is local even if it has a colon.
```

so whereas

```
$ tar -xf asset-v1\:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz
tar: Cannot connect to asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz: resolve failed
```

fails,

```
$ tar --force-local -xf asset-v1\:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz
```

succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're facing is the result of a file with a really poor name. You'll need to first rename the file, *then* extract the contents.

1. Rename the file to something simpler:

   ```
   mv asset-v1\:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+1T2020+type@asset+block@student-dist.tar.gz soe.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the contents:

   ```
   tar -xvf soe.tar.gz
   ```
3. Confirm you have files:

   ```
   ll
   total 5680
   drwxrwxr-x 10 jason jason    4096 12月 29 13:08 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 21 jason jason    4096 12月 29 13:06 ../
   drwxr-xr-x 11 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 assignments/
   drwxr-xr-x  3 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 bin/
   drwxr-xr-x  2 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 etc/
   drwxr-xr-x  2 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 examples/
   drwxr-xr-x  2 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 handouts/
   drwxr-xr-x 11 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 include/
   drwxr-xr-x  4 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 lib/
   -rw-rw-r--  1 jason jason 5773538  3月 28  2020 soe.tar.gz
   drwxr-xr-x 11 jason jason    4096  6月 18  2011 src/
   ```

When you see file names that contain characters such as `:` and `@`, it's often better to rename them if at all possible.